# Imap cyrillic mail

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I use the mailsystem.NET library to put a message in my inbox. This is my code:

```
Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client();
imap.ConnectSsl("imap.gmail.com", 993);
imap.Login(mylogin, mypassword);
Mailbox mails;
mails = imap.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
Message commomMessage = new Message();
commomMessage.From = new Address("someAddress", "someName");
commomMessage.To.Add(mylogin, "myName");
commomMessage.Subject = "someSubject";
commomMessage.BodyHtml.Text = "Привет мир";//or some cyrillic text 
commomMessage.Date = DateTime.Now;
mails.Append(commomMessage);
```

When I open my gmail inbox, I see this mail, but the body contains `????? ???` rather than "привет мир". If `commomMessage.BodyHtml.Text` contains only Latin characters, there is no problem.

Comment: See: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Message` class inherits from .NET's `MailMessage` class try using it's `BodyEncoding` property and set it to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`, for example:

```
commomMessage.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

If `Message` class doesn't inherit from `MailMessage` try to find other way of setting the appropriate encoding for your e-mail message. I believe it's the issue that you can fix by using UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Message class don't inherit from .NET's MailMessage class.

Comment: He has charset property,but when I set it to "utf-8" nothing happend